# Agrupar registros por dia

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Tenho a seguinte tabela

```
ID  |   Início   |   Fim      |   Horas
333 | 01/01/2017 | 03/01/2017 |    5
333 | 02/01/2017 | 05/01/2017 |    1
333 | 05/01/2017 | 07/01/2017 |    3
333 | 01/01/2017 | 07/01/2017 |    6
```

Preciso de um resultado assim

```
ID  | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 |...| 31
333 | 11 | 12 | 12 | 07 | 10 | 09 | 09 | 0 | 0
```

Estou fazendo a somatória de Horas agrupando pelos dias de Início e Fim.
Outro resultado que para minha necessidade daria na mesma seria este

```
ID  | Dia | Horas
333 | 01  |  11
333 | 02  |  12
333 | 03  |  12
333 | 04  |  07
333 | 05  |  10
333 | 06  |  09
333 | 07  |  09
333 | ... |  0
333 | 31  |  0
```

Comment: "Estou fazendo a somatória de Horas agrupando pelos dias de Início e Fim": os valores das tabelas 2 e 3 não coincidem com essa afirmação. Por exemplo, por essa regra o dia 2 teria somente 1 hora mas nas tabelas 2 e 3 o valor exibido é 12.

Comment: O intervalo pode iniciar em um mês e terminar em outro?

Comment: Sim, pode. Ou até anos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei optando pela seguinte solução

**Dados**

```
DECLARE @INI SMALLDATETIME = '20170101'
DECLARE @FIM SMALLDATETIME = '20170131'
DECLARE @TAB TABLE(
    ID INT
    ,INICIO SMALLDATETIME
    ,FIM SMALLDATETIME
    ,HORAS FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @TAB
SELECT 333, '20170101', '20170103', 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 333, '20170102', '20170105', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 333, '20170105', '20170107', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 333, '20170101', '20170107', 6
```

**Lógica**

```
;WITH sample AS (
SELECT INICIO AS dt, ID, HORAS, FIM
FROM @TAB
WHERE   (
            INICIO BETWEEN @INI AND @FIM
            OR FIM BETWEEN @INI AND @FIM
            OR (INICIO <= @INI AND FIM >= @FIM)
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, dt), S.ID, S.HORAS, FIM
    FROM sample s 
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) <= FIM
)

SELECT dt, SUM(HORAS) FROM sample
WHERE DT BETWEEN @INI AND @FIM
GROUP BY DT
ORDER BY DT
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Não vai exibir até o dia 31 mas eu consigo configurar isso do lado do cliente (componente gráfico)

Comment: Como comentei na resposta que postei, o macete é transformar o "intervalo de datas" em "datas individuais". A partir daí, é "mamão com açúcar", né? Dúvida: a coluna ID não deveria constar da cláusula GROUP BY?

Comment: No meu caso n precisa já que o id será sempre o mesmo.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode adicionar uma cláusula `GROUP BY YEAR(Início)`. Ou ainda, utilizar as duas colunas para agrupar o resultado.

Veja como funcionam as [funções de data e hora do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month).

Answer (score -1):

Pode usar o `SUM` e o `DAY` e o `MONTH` para pegar apenas o dia para cada mês.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    DAY (INICIO) AS DIA,
    MONTH (INICIO) AS MES,
    SUM(HORAS) AS HORAS
FROM
    TABELA
GROUP BY
    DAY (INICIO),
    MONTH (INICIO)
ORDER BY
    DAY (INICIO),
    MONTH (INICIO)
```

Comment: Alguém passou e negativou todas as respostas, exceto uma. O que me leva a pensar apenas em uma possibilidade. Agora, essa pessoa talvez queira me dizer o que está errado na minha resposta.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(INICIO) = 1 THEN HORAS ELSE 0 END) AS D01,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(INICIO) = 2 THEN HORAS ELSE 0 END) AS D02,
    ...
    SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(INICIO) = 31 THEN HORAS ELSE 0 END) AS D31 
FROM
    TABELA
```

Veja também Pivot e Unpivot    https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score -2):

Cada linha da tabela de entrada contém o ID de um objeto, um intervalo de datas e o número de horas registradas. Observa-se também que há sobreposição de datas nos intervalos; isto é, os intervalos se sobrepõem.

A partir de cada linha da tabela de entrada é necessário gerar várias linhas, uma para cada data do intervalo definido pelas colunas Início/Fim. Por exemplo, para a primeira linha da tabela de entrada,

333 | 01/01/2017 | 03/01/2017 |    5

são geradas as seguintes linhas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após essa transformação de "intervalo de datas" em "datas", calcular a soma das horas para cada ID/dia é um processo simples.

---

Para montar a terceira tabela, uma forma é

```
-- código #1 v2
-- informe o mês e ano
declare @Mês int, @Ano int;
set @Mês= 1;
set @Ano= 2017;

-- calcula o período de emissão
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set @DataInicial= Convert(date, '1/' + Cast(@Mês as varchar) +
                                 '/' + Cast(@Ano as char(4)), 103);
set @DataFinal= DateAdd(day, -1, DateAdd(month, +1, @DataInicial));

--
SELECT H.ID, Day(I.dt) as Dia, sum(H.Horas) as Horas
  from tbHoras as H
       cross apply dbo.GeraIntervalo (H.Início, H.Fim) as I
  where H.Fim >= @DataInicial
        or H.Início <= @DataFinal       
  group by H.ID, I.dt
  having I.dt between @DataInicial and @DataFinal
  order by H.ID, Dia;
go
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Já para obter o leiaute da segunda tabela, a técnica habitual é o pivoteamento.

```
-- código #2 v2
-- informe o mês e ano
declare @Mês int, @Ano int;
set @Mês= 1;
set @Ano= 2017;

-- calcula o período de emissão
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set @DataInicial= Convert(date, '1/' + Cast(@Mês as varchar) +
                                 '/' + Cast(@Ano as char(4)), 103);
set @DataFinal= DateAdd(day, -1, DateAdd(month, +1, @DataInicial));

--
with T3 as (
SELECT H.ID, I.dt, H.Horas
  from tbHoras as H
       cross apply dbo.GeraIntervalo (H.Início, H.Fim) as I
  where H.Fim >= @DataInicial
        or H.Início <= @DataFinal
),
T3_Mês as (
SELECT ID, day(dt) as Dia, Horas 
  from T3
  where dt between @DataInicial and @DataFinal
)  
SELECT ID, [01], [02], [03], [04], [05], [06], [07], [08], [09], [10],
       [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20],
       [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
  from T3_Mês
       pivot (sum(Horas) for Dia in ([01],[02],[03],[04],[05],[06],
                  [07],[08],[09],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],
                  [17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],
                  [27],[28],[29],[30],[31])) as P
go
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Foram utilizadas as seguintes funções:

```
-- código #3
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.GetNums') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@n AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  WITH
  L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
  L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
  L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
  L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
  L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
  Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5)
  SELECT TOP (@n) n FROM Nums ORDER BY n;
GO
```

Fonte: [Packing Date Intervals](http://sqlmag.com/blog/packing-date-intervals)

e

```
-- código #4
CREATE FUNCTION GeraIntervalo (@D1 date, @D2 date)
returns table as
return
with Datas as (
SELECT DateAdd(day, n-1, @D1) as dt
  from dbo.GetNums(DateDiff(day, @D1, @D2) + 1) as Nums
)
SELECT dt
  from Datas;
go
```

---

Código para gerar dados para teste.

```
-- código #5
CREATE TABLE tbHoras (ID int, Início date, Fim date, Horas tinyint);

INSERT into tbHoras values
  (333, '1/1/2017', '3/1/2017', 5),
  (333, '2/1/2017', '5/1/2017', 1),
  (333, '5/1/2017', '7/1/2017', 3),
  (333, '1/1/2017', '7/1/2017', 6),
  (337, '30/12/2016', '2/1/2017', 3),
  (337, '1/1/2017', '3/1/2017', 2),
  (337, '30/1/2017', '2/2/2017', 4);
go
```

Comment: Colunas com acentuação não são indicadas.